# Create a ComboBox object to pass it into a Sub

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I am trying to access a ComboBox on a UserForm from a sub. Therefore I'm trying to pass a Combobox object into it.

However, I don't seem to be able to create a Combobox Object in order to pass it in. They are always empty when entering the sub. This is what I've been trying:

```
Dim ctl As ComboBox

Set ctl = Me.cb_FcnName 'cb_FcnName is the name of the Combobox I'm trying to access

Call ColumnEntries2Combobox(ctl)
```

And this is my Sub:

```
Private Sub ColumnEntries2Combobox(ByRef Combo As ComboBox)
     Combo.AddItem = Worksheets(WorksheetName).Cells(currRow, 2)
End Sub
```

For some reason I can't seem to find any documentation on how to create the necessary combobox object to pass into the sub...

Thanks in advance for any kind of help!

Comment: You shouldnt have to create a new object, you can just use: `ColumnEntries2Combobox(cb_FcnName)`

Comment: I did just this in the beginning and I get a compilation error in the line in the Sub with the AddItem. It tells me that it expects a function or variable.

Comment: That code works for me. Explain "always empty when entering the sub"? How do you know? Is the ComboBox on a UserForm and the Sub in the same class module?

Comment: It should be `AddItem "foo"`, with a space, not equals. It is a method, not a property (that you would set equal to something).

Comment: Yes. The ComboBox is on a UserForm. I added the Info above...

Comment: @AndyG : That's better! Thanks! But now it tells me that access was denied!

Comment: The line with the AddItem. "Runtime Error 70: Access denied!"

Comment: How do I check if it's got focus?

Comment: Nevermind. If the ComboBox has its RowSource specified then you cannot dynamically add items.

Comment: That's been done previously in the programm. Can I undo it somehow within the sub? Set it to nothing?

Comment: This has gone beyond the original question and error. I suggest you open a new question and provide the current code and details.

Comment: Okay. Thanks so much for your help already. If you wanna post your solution to the original problem as an answer I'll accept it as the solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AddItem` is a method, not a property. For a method we supply arguments after a space, compared to setting a property equal to something.

So change

```
     Combo.AddItem = Worksheets(WorksheetName).Cells(currRow, 2)
```

to

```
     Combo.AddItem Worksheets(WorksheetName).Cells(currRow, 2)
```

This is a common error, so a simple demonstration is:

```
object.Property = value

object.Method arg1, arg2
```